# Visual Studio Code TypeScript compiler version

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

When I try to run a angular2 project I get the following error:

```
app/app.routes.ts(3,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

I figured that Visual Code Studio is not using the newest compiler, I checked and I have installed the latest version (1.8.10). I figured I could change the `"typescript.tsdk"` variable from null to the relative path. But when I save the settings.json the changes do not appear...

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your system variable PATH. Probably it contains path to old TypeScript compiler version (or the path to old version is before path to new version).